# chromium + web proxy

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, chromium

I am trying to set up a web proxy for chromium on my 12.10 lubuntu box. In firefox I simply add the address of the autoconfigure script `http://ipaddress/autoconfig` in the "Automatic proxy configuration" box in preferences->network->settings and it works perfectly.

In chromium I have tried various possible solutions, all of which have failed so far.  What is the right way to do this?

The solution given below works but uses the same proxy for all web pages and requires you to use a command line argument when you run chromium.

> Is there a way to do the equivalent of what firefox does? That is load
>   the autoconfigure script (a javascript file) telling chromium which
>   URLs should use the proxy (see e.g.
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config )?

That is I would like chromium to only use the proxy for selected pages. I would also like to  be able easily to turn the proxy on and off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant command line is

`chromium-browser -proxy-pac-url=<pac-file-url>`.

For the problem of not being able to change the settings within chromium, it is possible this extension will work http://code.google.com/p/switchysharp/ but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

In theory it should work when you set a system proxy.

You can try running from the command line

```
chromium  --proxy-server=host:port
```

change "host:port" to your proxy server.

If that works you can update the launcher or create a custom menu entry.

You may need to file a bug report.

---

And for the keyboard shortcut route, you could edit `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` (after ensuring you have a back-up). The example below refers to `google-chrome` because that's what I use with Privoxy; I use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to launch the "proxied" version from the keyboard:

```
<!-- Launch PrivoxyChrome -->
<keybind key="W-P">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --proxy-server=127.0.0.1:8118 %U</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

If you want the edit to `lubuntu-rc.xml` to take effect ASAP, run `openbox --reconfigure` in a terminal to refresh `lubuntu-rc.xml`.

Comment: I got `chromium-browser  --proxy-server=host:port:8080` to work. However it uses the proxy for all web pages. In firefox it only uses it for the ones it is needed for which is what I would like it to do.  Is this possible in chromium? I think this is what the autoconfigure script does in firefox.

Comment: Also, is there an extension that can you let you turn the web proxy on and off or do you really need to restart chromium and run it using a different command line to do this?

Comment: There are a few extensions for chromium that allow  you to manage your proxy. I have not used them recently.